# How interrupts and Thread.sleep()/Thread.join() act

Tags: java, multithreading

I would like to understand how interrupts work with Thread.sleep() and Thread.join().

For example, if in a thread, say `t1`, I execute `Thread.sleep()` and after from another thread I call `t1.interrupt()` then `Thread.sleep()` throws and InterruptException.

What I would like to know is the mechanism behing all this. As I see `sleep()` is a static method, how can it detect that an interrupt was sent to the thread which it was invoked from?

Similary for the case `t1.join()`, how can this method see that the thread that executed `ti.join()` has received an interrupt and throw and exception? Is there a sort of connection?

Comment: Considering that this is implementation and platform-specific, what insight to you expect to gain from an answer? how does that help you with some programming problem? i.e. what's the underlying motivation for your question.

Comment: sleep is static, since it only makes sense to call it on the currently running thread. When you take a look at the source of Thread, you can see that the methods like sleep and wait are native methods. This is the case, since the os handles threads (if they are native, which they are in java). So basically if oyu call interrupt, java redirects that interrupt to the os, then the os wakes the thread and then java throws the exception.

Comment: What does "native methods" mean? However what I don't understand is how Thread.sleep can understand which thread make sleep, how it can extract this information.

Comment: `native` methods are methods that are declared in a Java class, but implemented by a "native" library.  A native library is a file containing architecture-specific instructions that are directly executed by the host processor.  This is in contrast to normal Java methods which are compiled down to platform-independent _byte codes_ that are executed by a JVM running _on_ the host processor.  You can learn more by reading about the _Java Native Interface_.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to understand how interrupts work with Thread.sleep() and Thread.join().

It is too complicated to explain in detail.  The implementation is in mostly in native code (i.e. C++ code) that is part of the JVM codebase, and in the native thread support provided by the OS, etcetera.  The source code is available if want to read it.

> As I see `sleep()` is a static method, how can it detect that an interrupt was sent to the thread which it was invoked from?

The static method delegates to a `native` method that implements the `sleep` behavior.  That native method would most likely delegate to the OS-provided native thread library (e.g. pthreads) to find out the current thread ... if that is necessary.  (This >>is<< what happens in the Linux case.)

Interrupts are also dealt with in the native methods.  On Linux, the Java `native sleep` method calls `pthread_sleep`.  When the latter returns, the `native sleep` method calls  `pthread_interrupted` to find out if the `pthread_sleep` call was interrupted, and throws the Java exception if necessary.

> What does "native methods" mean?

These are methods that are not implemented in Java code.  Look at the source code for the `java.lang.Thread` class and you will see some methods that have the `native` modifier.  Those are native methods.